# Rending a Modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to learn AngularJS (background in BackboneJS). I have a **div** with some content inside, and I hope to render this **div** as a modal upon clicking inside of it:

```
<div class="stickynote"> Content here </div>
```

My thinking is to add a modal class that I can style in CSS. However, I'm not too sure how to add the modal class upon clicking (and conversely, removing the modal class upon clicking after the modal is rendered). Would I have to use `ng-click` and somehow set the class property from the JavaScript (**myApp.js**) file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own modal styling and if you simply want to achieve adding an extra item to `class` attribute of your element, you can use a combination of `ng-class` and `ng-click`:

```
<div class="stickynote" 
  ng-class="{yourModalCSSClass: isModalOpen}" 
  ng-click="isModalOpen = true">
```

And somewhere else, you need another `ng-click` to turn it off:

```
<button ng-click="isModalOpen = false">Close modal</button>
```

Beware that both `div` and `button` must be in the same `scope` hierarchy to be able to use the same `isModalOpen` value. And by the way, I haven't tried this code but this should give you an idea. If you have a controller/directive, you can set `isModalOpen` from there by introducing functions in the scope:

```
// controller
$scope.toggleModal = function () {
  $scope.isModalOpen = !$scope.isModalOpen;
}

<div ...
  ng-click="toggleModal()">

<button ng-click="toggleModal()">...
```

Comment: Thank you. I can open the modal successfully, but closing it doesn't do anything. I used your logic in closing the modal with

           `<button class="close-modal" ng-if="isModal==true" ng-click="isModal=false"> 
            Close Modal
           </button>`.

Comment: I used `ng-click="isModal=!(isModal==true)"` instead. This seems to work by just clicking on the div.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party solution, ng-dialog is an outstanding solution for modals+Angular.

https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog